# mysql join with limit 1

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have two tables in one to many relationship.

And, I want to select columns from each main record along with the first record from a related table.

I tried some ways but it just doesn't go...

Here I end up with this SQL fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/39fdb/3

The problem there is that it just cannot reference a.ID from a subselect.

This does not work, of course, but it's just all I could think of

```
select a.*,b.* from event a left join 
(select * from event_pictures where a.ID=article limit 1)
b on a.ID=b.article;
```

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

No, you can't reference `a.ID` in a subselect that is joined to `a`. You can do the following, but you better supply an ordering. Otherwise, there is no "first" row. A (more or less) random row from table b will be selected:

```
select a.*, b.* 
from event a 
  left join event_pictures b
    on b.PK =                        --- the PRIMARY KEY
       ( select bb.PK                --- of event_pictures 
         from event_pictures bb 
         where a.ID = bb.article
         ORDER BY bb.something 
         limit 1
       ) ;
```

Comment: I'll do an order of course, this is just a simplified version :) Yet even random record with an image might be ok... Let us see

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care which image gets returned for an article, you can select the `MIN` or `MAX` image grouped by article (rather than doing a `LIMIT 1`) in your subquery

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/39fdb/18)

Comment: I'm not an expert but it looks like group by will work slower and loop through each subset. I guess I would better stick with limit, and order them in the natural way by an auto increment ID field (which is kinda default isn't it?)

Comment: Agreed, I'd go with ypercube's more flexible answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could use min or max as suggested already:

```
select
    e.*,
    (
        select min(ep.img)
        from event_pictures as ep
        where ep2.article = e.article
    ) as img
from
    event as e
```

If you want img based on highest ID:

```
select
    e.*,
    (
        select ep2.img
        from event_pictures as ep2
        where ep2.ID = last_ep.last_ID
    ) as img
from
    event as e inner join -- could be a left join if necessary
    (
        select ep.article, max(ep.ID) as last_ID
        from event_pictures as ep
        group by ep.article
    ) as last_ep
        on last_ep.article = e.ID
```

Neither approach requires the use of `limit`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```
select e.*, ep.*
from (select e.*,
             (select article
              from event_pictures ep
              where ep.article = e.id
              order by rand()
              limit 1
             ) as eparticle
      from event e
     ) e left join
     event_pictures ep
     on e.eparticle = ep.article
```

The subquery finds one randome "article".  The information for this is then joined in.

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting scheme but a definitive overkill in my case :-)