# Return single record where multiple linked records exist in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have three tables

**POI** contains unique rows with an unique ID for each row

**Images** which may/may not contain multiple records for each poi

**Reviews** may also contain multiple records for each POI in table 1

I want to retrieve all rows from **Reviews** and if there is image in **Images** get the file name of the first record AND include name country from **POI**

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT
  Reviews.review_id,
  Reviews.poi_id,
  Reviews.review,
  POI.Name,
  Images.file
FROM
  Reviews
  LEFT JOIN POI ON Reviews.poi_id = POI.ID
  LEFT JOIN Images ON Reviews.poi_id = Images.ID
ORDER BY
  POI.Name;
```

But this is returning multiple records (i.e. a record for each image linked to the POI)
Can this be modified to just one record for each review even though there may be multiple images? Or

Comment: this might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6879391/mysql-join-with-limit-1-on-joined-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT
  Reviews.review_id
  Reviews.review_id,
  Reviews.poi_id,
  Reviews.review,
  POI.Name,
  SELECT (
    Images.file
    FROM Images 
    WHERE Reviews.poi_id = Images.ID
    ORDER BY Images.ID ASC
    LIMIT 1
  )
FROM
  Reviews
JOIN POI ON Reviews.poi_id = POI.ID
ORDER BY
  POI.Name;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want this:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT Reviews.review_id,
  Reviews.poi_id,
  Reviews.review,
  POI.Name,
  Images.file
FROM
  Reviews
  LEFT JOIN POI ON Reviews.poi_id = POI.ID
  LEFT JOIN Images ON Reviews.poi_id = Images.ID
ORDER BY
  POI.Name;
```

Let me know if that doesn't do what you want.