# Subquery with two columns

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, like so:

a.id, a.created, a.b
b.id, b.name, b.created

I want all the records from the table **b** to be sorted by the *a.created* timestamp.

I've been trying something of the following:

```
SELECT b.id, b.name FROM b JOIN a ON a.b = b.id ORDER BY b.created DESC
```

But it always returns multiple records from **b** when really all I want is one match of **a** for every row of **b**.

I tried to use a SELECT subquery:

```
SELECT b.id, b.name, (SELECT a.created AS a_c FROM a WHERE
a.b = b.id) AS a_c FROM b ORDER BY a_c DESC
```

But I also want to be able to pull a.id as well.

Is there a JOIN statement I could use or should I use two subqueries? This is going to be a pretty important function in my application so I want the performance to be above par!

Comment: Did you try ?
SELECT DISTINCT b.id, b.name FROM b JOIN a ON a.b = b.id ORDER BY b.created DESC

Comment: If you want to pull `a.id` as well, and there are multiple matching rows of `a`, which one do you want to pull?

Comment: @Barmar I want to match the newest record of `a`. e.g. `ORDER BY a.created DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: You need to do a sub-select and join into that.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT b.id AS bid, b.name, a.id AS aid, a.created
FROM b
JOIN (SELECT a1.id, a1.b, a1.created
      FROM a AS a1
      JOIN (SELECT id, MAX(created) AS maxcreate
            FROM a
            GROUP BY id) AS a2
      ON a1.id = a2.id AND a1.created = a2.maxcreate) AS a
ON b.id = a.b
ORDER BY a.created DESC
```

The subquery gets the row in `a` with the newest create date for each `id`. Then you join this with `b`.

Answer (score 1):

```
select b.id, b.name, a.id a_id, a.created
from b join (
    select b, max(a.created) max_created
    from a
    group by b
) t1 on t1.b = b.id
join a on a.b = b.id and a.created = t1.max_created
order by a.created desc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select
   b.id
  ,b.name
  ,b.created as b_created
  ,a.created as a_created 
from b
left join a
join (
   select b, max(created) as max_creatd
   from a
   group by b
)a_min
   on a_min.b = a.b
  and a_min.max_creatd = a.created
   on a.b   = b.id
```

which for these datasets (SQL Server syntax to avoid writing a ton of DDL):

```
a as (select * from (values
     ('A1','20140701 23:11:59', 'B1')
    ,('A2','20140701 22:11:59', 'B1')
  )a(id,created,b)
```

and

```
b as ( select * from (values
    ('B1', 'Bob', '20140701 11:59:59')
   ,('B2', 'Bub', '20140701 10:59:59')
  )b(id,name,created)
```

returns the following:

```
id   name b_created         a_created
---- ---- ----------------- -----------------
B1   Bob  20140701 11:59:59 20140701 23:11:59
B2   Bub  20140701 10:59:59 NULL

(2 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just joining the tables as [suggested in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6879391/mysql-join-with-limit-1-on-joined-table/24442655#24442655).

```
SELECT b.id, b.name, a.id AS a_id FROM b JOIN a ON
a.id = (SELECT a.id FROM a WHERE a.b=b.id ORDER BY 
a.created DESC LIMIT 1)
```