# MySQL hierarchy relation in the same table : how to exclude parents?

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a table like this :

```
DESC mytable

id  | parent
1   | 2
2   | null
3   | null
4   | null
5   | 3
... | ...
```

3 kind of entries :

- Entry which is not a parent and has no parent (ex: 4)
- Entry which is not a parent and has a parent (ex: 1,5)
- Entry which is a parent [and has no parent] (ex: 2,3)

I'm trying to get every row which are not a parent.

At first I tried this :

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT parent FROM mytable);
```

It was too slow, so I tried this :

```
SELECT m.* FROM mytable m
# tmp.* will contain the first child
LEFT JOIN mytable tmp ON tmp.parent = m.id
# only rows with no children
WHERE tmp.id IS NULL
```

But it is still too slow...

On my second query, I know that MySQL fetch every children but only store the first one in tmp.*, but I can't find an **efficient** way to limit the search to 1 child. (I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6879391/mysql-join-with-limit-1-on-joined-table) and on other websites)

Do you have any idea on how I could improve exec time ?

Thanks for any help

Comment: if you're trying to get every row that is not a parent, why couldn't you just do `select * from mytable where parent is not null`

Comment: look at my example table, 2 is a parent but has no parent. And 4 is not a parent and has no parent

Comment: Oh ok I was assuming that all non-parents were children of some other member of the hierarchy, but that's really only part of the equation.

Comment: I made an edit to explain what kind of entry we have

Comment: Do you have an index on the `parent` column? That might go some way in explaining why the query is so slow. Personally, I prefer `WHERE EXISTS` (or in this case `NOT EXISTS`) for cases like these.

Comment: Ok, I'll look this way and come back

Comment: The solution was to add an index on the `parent` field

Answer (score 2):

A join would work of course, but you could also use exists... I'm not sure which one will run better in an explain. It might help if you index the parent column as well.

Try this:

```
SELECT m.* FROM mytable m WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mytable WHERE parent = m.ID)
```

Comment: You should edit to `WHERE parent = m.ID` if I'm correct.

Comment: The average exec time is still the same, I'm going to try an index