# Select only specific portion of OneToMany joined collection

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony

I am new to symfony so sorry if this is something really simple to anwer.

For the sake of example I have rewritten code snippets as if I was writing a blog.
I have a `BlogPost` entity with collection of `BlogComment`s annotated like this:

```
 /**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="BlogComment", mappedBy="post")
 */
private $comments;
```

From my amateur point of view, Doctrine likes to work with complete objects, so this collection is either not initialized, or lazily loaded whenever I use the reference to it.

I guess you can imagine the overhead and memory requirements when every one of my `BlogPost`s has at least 500 `Blogcomment`s and they all get initialized whenever I touch `$comments` variable.

What I am trying to achieve is to list ie. 50 blog posts, each with 20 latest comments (without the memory explosion). Additionally, I would like to be able to display only top 20 comments with most "likes" (or generally just select a subset based on some criteria).

Is there any generally recommended and clean way to achieve this kind of functionality? And when I achieve this, isn't use of such "incomplete" or "modified" entities going to break my logic (when updating/deleting items from the subset and persisting it)? I assume that solution to this will likely be a method in a custom repository, but I still can't see the thought behind it.

In advance, thank you for answers, I am really curious what kinds of solutions you will be able to come up with.

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine is not good to deal with a big list objets. It will be far slower than a classic SQL query followed by `while ($row = $stmt->fetch())`. Sometimes, it's better to perform native queries. 50 blogs posts * 20 comments = 1000 objects populated, and even probably more if you get the User name for each result.

You will need to use a native query anyway, because I don't think you can get your 20 comments per blog post with a pure DQL query. You will need to do some joined subquery to limit to 20 comments, see this post for more information: [MySQL JOIN with LIMIT 1 on joined table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6879391/mysql-join-with-limit-1-on-joined-table)

Once you have done your native query, and if you really need your objects, you can bind your results to Doctrine entities with the ResultSetMappingBuilder: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html#resultsetmappingbuilder

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will definitely look into that. I can write the query in SQL without a problem. :) My other idea was to call another repository to fetch `BlogComment`s for the post and then manually assign them to `$comments` variable for each `BlogPost`...is that a wrong way of thinking in symfony/doctrine?

Comment: It's not a wrong way, but I would be  really better to do it with only one good query : less work for your database, and better possibility to use a cache on the Doctrine side. In term of Doctrine, one query or several won't change a lot of thing, since its work is to take a row (an array) and transform it into a PHP object. He don't really cares if you do it with one or several queries.