# Make limit to Join MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo, phpmyadmin

Here in my code i can't make limit for each joined table, I see always 
Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN products_images ON products.id=products_images.product_id LIMIT 1 ' at line 4

```
SELECT products_images.image as products_image, products_description.name as products_name, products_details.price as products_price, products.id as products_id
FROM products
INNER JOIN products_description ON products.id=products_description.product_id LIMIT 1
INNER JOIN products_images ON products.id=products_images.product_id LIMIT 1
INNER JOIN products_details ON products.id=products_details.product_id LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL JOIN with LIMIT 1 on joined table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6879391/mysql-join-with-limit-1-on-joined-table)

Answer (score 0):

That is because that is invalid syntax. If you want to limit the rows compared from joined tables you need to replace those tables with subqueries on those tables.

Making a few assumptions about the result you want, a simple example would be replacing

`INNER JOIN products_description ON products.id=products_description.product_id LIMIT 1`

with

`INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM products_description AS d WHERE d.product_id = product.id ORDER BY d.id DESC LIMIT 1) AS pd`

*I would NOT recommend this exact subquery though as correlated subqueries (the subquery's WHERE references the outer query) are usually rather inefficient; it will be separately executed for every row in `products`.* 
Usually, such subqueries should find the "first for each" including (and often GROUPing on) the id of "each" and then be JOINed on that id; as that avoids costly correlation.

Comment: I don't know how, please help me

Comment: see edit, and try searching for "mysql first for each" or "mysql last for each"