# How to limit and search number of joined rows from table in multiple joins in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a following tables in MySQL database:

```
+------------------------+
|          Users         |
+----+--------+----------+
| id | name   | role     |
+----+--------+----------+
| 1  | Martin | admin    |
+----+--------+----------+
| 2  | George | admin    |
+----+--------+----------+
| 3  | John   | employee |
+----+--------+----------+

+-------------------------+
|          Forms          |
+----+--------------------+
| id | type               |
+----+--------------------+
| 10 | marketing_form     |
+----+--------------------+
| 11 | client_survey_form |
+----+--------------------+
| 12 | client_survey_form |
+----+--------------------+

+---------------------------------------------+
|              UsersAssignToForms             |
+----+---------+---------+--------------------+
| id | user_id | form_id | additional_comment |
+----+---------+---------+--------------------+
| 20 | 1       | 10      | Lorem ipsum...     |
+----+---------+---------+--------------------+
| 21 | 2       | 10      | Lorem ipsum....    |
+----+---------+---------+--------------------+
| 22 | 3       | 10      | null               |
+----+---------+---------+--------------------+
| 23 | 3       | 11      | null               |
+----+---------+---------+--------------------+
```

I would like to have result:

```
+---------+---------+------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| user_id | form_id | first_name | form_type          | additional_comment |
+---------+---------+------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| 1       | 10      | Martin     | marketing_form     | Lorem ipsum...     |
+---------+---------+------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| 3       | 11      | John       | client_survey_form | null               |
+---------+---------+------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| null    | 12      | null       | client_survey_form | null               |
+---------+---------+------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

First of all i would like to limit number of users returned from join query (one user per one form). If user with `admin` role is assigned to form i would like to display this user (prioritize `admin` role over `employee` role) and limit number of returned users to 1, if `admin` is not assign, but `employee` is assigned query should return this user, if no-one is assign query should return nulls (left or right join probably).

I saw this question on stackoverflow - [MySQL JOIN with LIMIT 1 on joined table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6879391/mysql-join-with-limit-1-on-joined-table), but unfortunately first answer has n+1 issue and rest of answers was made with simple one join. **For my purposes i need to join more tables** but wouldn't like to design this tables above to clarify what i would like to achieve, but it's very important.

So my query will looks like probably:

```
SELECT u.id, f.id, u.name, f.type, uf.additional_comment, [more selects from other tables...] FROM Forms as f
LEFT JOIN Users as u ON ......
INNER JOIN UsersAssignToForms as uf ON .....
[here i would like to put more and more inner joins.....]
```

Comment: Where does form id 12 come from?

Comment: Is there any logic for this row where null with different form id which is not existed in your given data?

Comment: Sry, i forget to modify Forms table with form that is assign to no-one. I've just updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySql >= 8.0 you can number the rows using some criteria (for each `Form` starting from one and `order by u.role ASC and u.id ASC`), then you can filter rows with number one:

```
WITH sq AS (SELECT u.id AS user_id, f.id AS form_id, u.name, f.type, uf.additional_comment,
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY f.id ORDER BY u.role ASC, u.id ASC) AS num
       
            FROM Forms AS f
            LEFT JOIN UsersAssignToForms AS uf ON f.id = uf.form_id
            LEFT JOIN Users AS u ON u.id = uf.user_id)
            
SELECT *
FROM sq
WHERE num = 1;
```

Before MySql 8.0 you can try something like this (the idea is the same but with different implementation):

```
SELECT sq2.user_id, sq2.form_id, sq2.name, sq2.type, sq2.additional_comment
FROM (
    SELECT 
           sq1.*,
           
           @row_number:=CASE WHEN @form_id = sq1.form_id THEN @row_number + 1 ELSE 1 END AS num,
           @form_id:= sq1.form_id
        
    FROM (SELECT u.id AS user_id, f.id AS form_id, u.name, f.type, uf.additional_comment
          FROM Forms AS f
          LEFT JOIN UsersAssignToForms AS uf ON f.id = uf.form_id
          LEFT JOIN Users AS u ON u.id = uf.user_id
          ORDER BY f.id ASC, u.role ASC, u.id ASC) AS sq1
          
    ORDER BY sq1.form_id) AS sq2

WHERE sq2.num = 1;
```

Comment: what about databases in version under 8 ?

Comment: I updated my answer with a query to MySql before 8.0 using the same idea.